# React Native Error: WebView has been removed from React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I upgraded expo sdk from 33 to the latest for maintenance of old source code.
The following error occurred when running the app after the upgrade:

```
Invariant Violation: WebView has been removed from React Native. It can now be installed and imported from 'react-native-webview' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview
```

To solve this issue, Iinstalled the latest version of react-native-webview.

And I imported this library.
However, when I run the app, the same problem still appears.
Even if I remove all the code that uses WebView, the same problem continues to be output.

Can I know how to solve this?

// package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "metro-config": "0.57.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "^4.0.1",
    "@expo/samples": "~3.0.3",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.6",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "expo": "^45.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.5.0",
    "expo-blur": "^12.0.1",
    "expo-camera": "~12.2.0",
    "expo-cli": "^6.2.1",
    "expo-constants": "~13.1.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "^11.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "^14.1.0",
    "expo-linking": "~3.1.0",
    "expo-location": "^15.0.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.15.4",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~10.2.1",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "immutable": "^4.2.2",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "qs": "^6.11.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-geocode": "^0.2.3",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-dash": "^0.0.11",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-maps": "0.30.2",
    "react-native-measureme": "^0.0.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^14.0.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-push-notification-popup": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-qrcode": "^0.2.7",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.26.1",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-actions": "^2.6.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-pender": "^2.0.12",
    "underscore": "^1.13.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

// component.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Header } from "../../components";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

class TermWebViewScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const type = navigation.getParam("type");
    const title =
      type === "pri" ? "개인정보 수집 및 이용동의" : "서비스 약관동의";
    return { header: <Header navigation={navigation} title={title} /> };
  };

  state = {
    pri: "https://mrhomes.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/documents/homes_privacy.html",
    usage:
      "https://mrhomes.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/documents/homes_term.html",
  };

  render() {
    const { pri, usage } = this.state;
    const type = this.props.navigation.getParam("type");

    return (
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: type === "pri" ? pri : usage }}
        style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
        startInLoadingState
        scalesPageToFit
      />
    );
  }
}

export default TermWebViewScreen;
```

Comment: have you tried to clean project after npm install  before run?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to clean up the source code after installing npm.

Comment: after cleaning if still you are facing issue then you need to check in whole project that ```WebView``` is not used from ```react-native``` in any file 
Can you find it in whole project ?